# What is the best practice for data table filters?

Tags: filter, data-tables, sort

For best user experience, what is the best practice for data table filters with  10+ columns?

**User's Goal:**

The user is trying to filter the list using of various filter types dates, number and keywords. Their end goal is to export the filtered data in CSV, PDF, etc.

1. **A separate filter side or top panel (like in Agile CRM, Trello)**

   [image]
2. **Individual filter options for each table header (like in Excel)**

   [image]

Comment: Can you give more context of what the user is trying to do? What's the domain, and is the app used by experts on a frequent basis? Any mocks will help us to assess your situation.

Comment: The user is trying to filter the list using of various filter types dates, number and keywords. Their end goal is to export the filtered data in csv, pdf etc.

Comment: Do you have any research on the filters? You may find many of them remain completely unused. Secondly, you're comparing apples with oranges. Excel's filters are taken from values in the column, the top example is the name of the column, and you supply the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution 1. shows the filtered options while solution 2. does not.

Before any conclusion, **you need to know if your users prefer or need to see the filtered options** before exporting.

Another aspect to consider is whether your end-users are highly used to manipulate spreadsheets software (like Excel). This may push you towards solution 2. regardless of supposed efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what your filtering effects. If its to filter the entire table, having the filter external to the table is fine. If it is to filter a specific category it needs to be with the content it effects.

Comment: Yes, the filter effects the entire table. The user is trying to filter the list using of various filter types dates, number and keywords. Their end goal is to export the filtered data in csv, pdf etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is [another filtering](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-general/filtering) presentation, used in the Shield UI Grid.

Answer (score 0):

I will go with **option 2**. IMO, as a UX/UI designer, we want to have a clean table both desktop and mobile views. Because if you have too many call-to-actions (let's say edit, delete, add, primary toggle filters, etc,.) and then if you want the filter tags to be seen then the table UI becomes cluttered.

Having the filter per column makes the table clean.