# Best way to organize data table

Tags: tables, data-tables

I want to design a data table, the table will have at least 6 columns and infinite rows (huge number).

I will display the table pagewise by limiting the number of rows per page.

I want to provide the user with table functionality as much as possible, ex- sorting filtering, etc

I have two questions,

1) what is the best and intuitive way to provide the filtering feature when the column is large?

2) How to provide the sorting function to the user? The best way known is to provide the sorting when the user clicks on the header and since the table is pagewise, how to provide the local sorting(i.e only sort the page) and global sort (sort entire content of the database)?

Please note: **Table is used to display only on desktop.**

Comment: Similar to https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/38526/adding-paging-sorting-and-filtering-toolbars-to-a-table

Comment: Similar to https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/109710/what-is-the-best-practice-for-data-table-filters

Comment: There are some similar questions that you can reference in terms of general layout and filtering of data tables, but if you have a more specific question in which you can present some mockups or more specific UI/UX problems then it will be more suitable for the UXSE forum.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) what is the best and intuitive way to provide the filtering option when the column is large?

One option would be to have a "add filter" button. The user clicks it, then selects the columns to filter, then finally the filter value/range. That way, you only show a list of filter fields that the user is interested in rather than them all in one go.

Another option, each column header should have a filter button. You click the button, it shows a popup where they select the filter value/range, then they apply it (update your results). If you use this method make sure it is very clear which columns have filters applied. Perhaps make them a different colour, and/or a line of disclaimer text above/below the results saying "one or more filters are applied to these results", for example.

> 2) How to provide the sorting function to the user, the best way to know is to provide the sorting when the user clicks on the header.

Sorting by clicking column header makes sense, most users know that is how to sort.

However, you can't just sort "the current page". You need to apply the sort to all data and then only return the data relevant to the selected page.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is this specific to desktop or mobile, or does it need to work on both?
2. What do you mean by "when the column is large"?
3. Why would a user only want to sort the current page? All pages would be relevant, wouldn't they?

Comment: by large column i mean exactly that, suppose I have only 2 columns then to provide filtering I can just create 2 form field relating to the 2 columns, but when the column is 10 suppose, I cant just create 10 forms for filtering for 10 columns, hence what would be the best way to provide the filtering option when the column is large.

Comment: your 3rd, point seems logical, maybe I don't need the sorting function to k=just sort current page.  This solves one of my doubts